# Cannot pass STDIN using shell_exec() in PHP

Tags: java, php, linux, bash, ubuntu

I am a complete beginner in PHP.

I want to execute a java .jar file using PHP.The jar file takes input from `STDIN` and generates the output at `STDOUT`.To execute the jar file this is what I do in my Ubuntu Linux terminal:

```
./java/bin/java -jar abc.jar
<here goes the STDIN>
Ctrl+D
<The output gets generated here at the STDOUT>
```

This works perfect.However when I replicate this in PHP as:

```
$p=shell_exec("./java/bin/java -jar abc.jar $s 0<&-");
```

This sends `$p` the output generated when `STDIN` is empty.Which definitely means that `$s` is not being passed.I am perfectly sure my jar file works perfectly,it's the php script where my mistake is.Can anyone please point out my mistake? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are using `$s` as an argument.  Did you mean for that streamed in?

Comment: Yes @Flosculus you are right I am passing `$s` as a argument and it is a Java program but I assure you I don't want to redirect the Java program as a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Complete shot in the dark, but:

```
$p=shell_exec(sprintf('./java/bin/java -jar abc.jar "%s" 0<&-', addslashes($s)));
```

It could be a case that `$s` contains unescaped characters that ruin the command syntax.